# I want to Add additional data to GTM data layer in magento2.3.6

Tags: magento2, google-tag-manager, magento-2.3, google-datalayer

I want to add some additional values(price, brand) to the existing datalayer event(productCLick event)in my magento 2.3.6.

```
function myFunction(id,price,brand,productUrl) {
    dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'productClick',
        'ecommerce': {
            'click': {
                'actionField': {'list': 'Catalog Page'},
                'products': [{
                    'id':id,
                    'price': price,                      // Name or ID is required.
                    'brand': brand
                }]
            }
        },
        'eventCallback': function() {
            document.location = productUrl
        }
    });
}
```

I implemented using onclick and am sending the custom data via parameters

Comment: Follow URL:- 
Product Clicks (for category, up-sell, cross-sell and search results) - Wherever you are showing list of products. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-clicks

Comment: I am wondering why it is not working.. i applied this solution in my product/list.phtml using onlick function..however didnt work for me.. am i missing anything.. not sure

Comment: Please share code if possible.

Comment: <script>
        function myFunction(id,price,brand,productUrl) {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'productClick',
            'ecommerce': {
                'click': {
                    'products': [{
                        'id':id,
                        'price': price, 
                        'brand': brand
                    }]
                }
            },
            'eventCallback': function() {
                document.location = productUrl
            }
        });
    }
</script>

Comment: "It is not working" is not a very good descripton of the problem. What do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening?